# How to back up a Google Apps Script's scriptdb

Tags: google-apps-script

If I have a mission critical db, that needs to be regularly backed up, and I store it as a scriptdb in GAS, is there any way to back up the actual database file? It seems the db is embedded in a way that makes it invisible outside of scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found decent soluton for my question above, in an unexpected place. Rather than use a scriptdb, I can use Google Fusion Table/s - these have SQL-type access, are concrete docs that can be exported, backed up, viewed etc, and can act as the data store for my app...

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can always query all your values and `JSON.stringify` them.
If you ever need to restore a database you from this, the only difference I can notice is that each item id will change.

Here is an example:

```js
function backupDB() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var res = db.query({});
  var array = [];
  while( res.hasNext() )
    array.push(res.next().toJson());
  var dbString = JSON.stringify(array);
  Logger.log(dbString); //you'll obviously save this string somewhere else e.g. as a docs file
}
```

You may also need to do this in chunks, as your db may have too much data for the script to handle at once, like this.

I also feel that this "backup" procedure should be taken care of by the API as well. The code above is just an idea I just had.

Comment: Yeah that is a good workaround, but I'm hoping Apps Script is going to have something more embedded. If people are going to be entrusting critical data to scriptdb, it only makes sense to be able to back it up in a robust, regular manner

Comment: Having the code backup its data by itself automatically (e.g. using a time-driven trigger) seems pretty robust to me, if you have something "that" critical running as an apps script, you should be a good enough developer to write a just as "critical" backup. But again, yes, something more "embedded" would be very good indeed. Now, if you meant this to be an "enhancement request" and not a real question, you're in the wrong place. You should file one in [Apps Script Issue Tracker].(http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: If you follow the good practice to create, use and rely on your-script-created ID re-importing will have no side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer is: you do not store mission critical data on a scriptdb, for many reasons:

1. appscript does not have SLA. Google has many other storages that do have guarantees.
2. Because that db does not support transactions you will not be able to guarantee that a batch process might process twice the same data (in cases where the script fails in the middle of a chunk backup or restore).
3. It will get complex if you store the ids inside other objects in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can copy your critical data from the scriptdb to a Google Spreadsheet. Given its a example in Google developers I think it is an interesting option.

Here is the link: [Copy a Database to a New Sheet in a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#copy_a_database_to_a_new_sheet_in_a_spreadsheet).